# Sometimes processor fan spins faster & makes noise

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, fan

The specification of my desktop computer is as

Processor: AMD FX 8320, Motherboard: Asus M5A97, RAM: Kingston HyperX 16 GB (8*2), HD: 1TB WD Black, Graphics Card: 2GB Saphire 5450, SMPS: Cooler Master 650W, OS: Windows 10

Sometimes its processor fan spins faster and makes noise (especially when I use virtual machine) and after this activity the computer shuts down automatically.

I diagnosed SMPS, RAM & HD. All are working fine.

I contacted technician. Sometimes the computer shuts down in 30 min and sometimes it works fine whole day. That’s why issue couldn’t get identified.

What can I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: "Sometimes its processor fan spins faster and makes noise (especially when I use a virtual machine) and after this activity, the computer shuts down automatically." - Your machine is attempting to maintain an operating temperature.  "Sometimes the computer shuts down in 30 min" - This indicates your system is overheating.  You should start by cleaning your machine.  If that still does not solve the problem upgrade the heatsink and fan.

Comment: I already removed dusts and cleaned inside the cabinet using a blower. There are three fans on the cabinet (two 5mm and one 12mm). All components (Processor, RAM, HD, etc.) are about two and half years old. The processor heatsink is the same that came with the processor which is tightly fitted with processor and on board.What next I need to do?

Comment: upgrade the heatsink and fan

Comment: @user249711 - Does not change the fact you have a cooling problem.  It sounds like you need to increase the airflow.

Comment: I also noticed that it’s related to heating issue of processor but please elaborate “upgrade the heatsink and fan”. Do I need to replace existing cabinet fans or buy new fans for cabinet? And do I need to replace existing heatsink or buy new heatsink for the processor?

Comment: Also check application CPU usage in Task Manager. Is something hogging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a Asus M5a97, mine is the R2.0. 
Everyone commenting is absolutely correct. I ordered it with the FX-8320 from tigerdirect. The CPU fan and heatsink needed to be replaced within a couple months. That motherboard auto shuts down to prevent damage to the hardware.

I would recommend using the amd cool n quiet software that came with the motherboard, it has to be activated in the bios. Additionally it has to have software installed on the host os's to fully utilize it's benefits.

This motherboard has the am3+ socket, look at your favorite retailers for a larger CPU heatsink and fan.

I put something similar to this on it and never looked back. http://m.tigerdirect.com/products/301868

P.s make sure you get decent thermal compound to put on the CPU. Neither the original heatsink or it's replacement came with quality compound.

Comment: As you said, “That motherboard auto shuts down to prevent damage to the hardware” and “The CPU fan and heatsink needed to be replaced within a couple months.” So does it mean, auto shutdown is because of motherboard feature not because of fault of motherboard and it prevents damage to the hardware and it can be resolved by replacing CPU fan and heatsink?

Comment: AMD FX 8320 came with CPU fan and heat sink also in the box. The same CPU fan and heat sink used while assembling the desktop. Since it’s assembled (about two and half years ago), I never removed processor, fan and heatsink from the motherboard. I heard it’s recommended to use processor brand and original CPU fan and heat sink so please guide me for this.

Comment: Yes, it can be resolved with a better fan and heatsink. I'm surprised yours lasted that long!

Comment: The brand and type is your own personal preference. I went with "cool master" the link I left was to show the style I upgraded to.

Comment: I was thinking that this issue is because of fault of motherboard and I need to buy another motherboard.

Comment: Please let me know which one is better http://www.thermaltake.com/products-model.aspx?id=c_00002881 or http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/hyper-103/. The first one is same that you shared in your link.

Comment: I can't give you shopping recommendations, it's off topic here. As a rule of thumb, the more square millimeters there are for cooling fins, the better it will cool. I personally go with a bigger slower rpm fan, they seem to last alot longer than smaller fans with higher rpm.

Comment: Fortunately my processor FX-8320 is still in warranty. That’s why I received a new processor in the replacement. After installing the new processor, I see at every start, “New CPU installed! Please enter setup to configure your system. Press F1 to Run SETUP” 
After pressing F1, I press F8 for Boot Menu, then I select P3:WDC.. Then I see Windows login screen. Please let me know, what I need to do?

Comment: It sounds like you are losing settings from the cmos on each boot. This should be asked as a new question, it has nothing to do with the fan replacement.

Comment: Okay. Now it’s not making noise but I noticed that CPU Fan speed increases frequently up to 5000 RPM even in basic activities like browsing internet and doing basic documentation. Earlier I used to turn on 3-4 virtual machines. Now I am afraid of durability of CPU Fan and other components.

Comment: This is exactly why I told you to upgrade it to a larger heatsink... I'm assuming you are using the cool n quiet software, it should help some. My original was very loud in everyday operation. Large fan & low rpm is what I went with. It quiet and does it's job well

Comment: Also, did you get better thermal compound as I recommended?

Comment: Earlier I downloaded Cool-n-Quiet but it couldn’t get executed because of compatibility issue. Now I don’t find Cool-n-Quiet Application for Windows 10 64-bit on https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/M5A97/HelpDesk_Download/ and https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/HelpDesk_Download/ 
That’s why I am not using Cool-n-Quiet Application. 
As per larger heat sink, I found at http://www.thermaltake.com/Cooler/Air_Cooler_/Riing/C_00002930/Riing_Silent_12_Pro_Blue_CPU_Cooler/design.htm whose cost is around 8K-9K INR. And it seems more expensive for me this time.

Comment: If this answered your original question please mark it as answered.